# Why does PyLint warn about no __init__?

Tags: python, pylint

We have numerous python classes that do not seem to need `__init__`, initialising them empty is either perfectly acceptable or even preferable. PyLint seems to think this is a bad thing. Am I missing some insight into why having no `__init__` is a Bad Smell? Or should I just suppress those warnings and get over it?

Comment: Do these classes have no attributes at all, or do you add attributes after the object is created?

Comment: Either. In the former case, I can see that that is itself a bad smell, but not oen I want ot go into right now. In the latter case, I'd rather have the Attribute Exception if I try using it before meaningful initialisation.

Comment: would you have some code and pylint output to show? Pylint usually complains about __init__ for some reason. If really not, then it needs a fix :)

Comment: @sthenault, I don't think it is a Pylint error as such, it is correct that there is no `__init__`. I was more asking whether I was using a horribly non-Pythonic idiom, which I think I am not.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What are you using these classes for?

If they are just a grouping of functions that do not need to maintain any state, there is no need for an `__init__()` but it would make more sense to just move all of those functions into their own module.

If they do maintain a state (they have instance variables) then you should probably have an `__init__()` so that those variables can be initialized.  Even if you never provide values for them when the class is created, it is generally a good idea to have them defined so that your method calls are not referencing instance variables that may or may not exist.

That being said, if you don't need an `__init__()`, feel free to ignore that warning.

**edit:** Based on your comment, it seems like you are fine with the AttributeError you will get on referencing variables before initialization.  That is a perfectly fine way to program your classes so in that case ignoring the warning from PyLint is reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you will at least use the `__init__()` method to initialize instance variables. If you are not doing this, then by all means turn off that warning.

Comment: Well, when we are talking about a pytest class it should have no init according to the pytest docs.  So, configuring a pylinrc to ignore W0232 for the test path seems reasonable